# How to fix subprocess.Popen locking up input

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, subprocess

I have a script that displays a menu which offers options to record and download livestreams and vods. The menu is set up like this:

```
Menu

1) Record
2) Download
3) ...

Choose your option: ...
```

The script calls multiple functions located in seperate scripts to request, parse, record or download streams. The problem is, when calling the record function, subprocess.Popen locks up my menu until the streams ends. I believe this has to do with the function claiming all stdin? How do I prevent the menu from locking up?

I've tried using the subprocess option `stdin=open(os.devnull)`. This won't lock up the menu, but results in a zombie process after the stream is done. Using threading like `Thread(target=record.record,args=[json_data,ua_ffmpeg,username,id]).start()` neither worked.

**menu.py**

```
import functions.record as record
  ...
  record.record(json_data,ua_ffmpeg,username,id)
  ...
```

**record.py**

```
  def record(json_data,ua_ffmpeg,username,id):
    ...
    subprocess.Popen('ffmpeg -icy 0 -headers "%s" -i %s -c copy -loglevel quiet videos/%s/livestreams/%s.ts' % (ua_ffmpeg, hls_url, username, id), shell=True)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you mean `Popen.communicate()` by saying `subprocess.Popen locks up my menu until the streams ends` ? If so, maybe you should try other ways as it will wait until the subprocess terminates.

Comment: "I've tried using the subprocess option `stdin=open(os.devnull)`. This won't lock up the menu, but results in a zombie process after the stream is done." Really? I thought ffmpeg worked fine with `< /dev/null`. Maybe you need to specify `-nostdin` explicitly in your command line.